# datatable datetime query for GMT time zone in r

Tags: r, datatable

I have a datetime record in GMT. When I query the datetime for a range using data.table I'm getting the records offset by 1 hour which I guess is due to data.table function based on UTC. How do I get a proper solution around this problem without converting the table to a UTC timezone.

```
df <- data.frame(TIMESTAMP = c("2021-06-18 11:36:00", "2021-06-18 11:38:00", "2021-06-18 11:40:00", "2021-06-18 11:42:00", "2021-06-18 11:44:00","2021-06-18 11:46:00", "2021-06-18 11:48:00"))


TIMESTAMP
1: 2021-06-18 11:36:00
2: 2021-06-18 11:38:00
3: 2021-06-18 11:40:00
4: 2021-06-18 11:42:00
5: 2021-06-18 11:44:00
6: 2021-06-18 11:46:00

start = c(ymd_hms("2021-06-18 11:36:00"))
end = c(ymd_hms("2021-06-18 11:44:00"))
library(data.table)
range <- data.table(start = start, end = end)
Event_1 <- setDT(df)[TIMESTAMP %inrange% range]
```

For code above no records returned. However when below time applied (1 hr before) the output is a perfect match. I tried adding tz="GMT" after the time but it didn't work.

```
start = c(ymd_hms("2021-06-18 10:36:00"))
end = c(ymd_hms("2021-06-18 10:44:00"))
```

Comment: it would be pleasant if you'd provide working code, not that one hast to manually construct df from your listing. And also mention the libraries you use, e.g. lubridate

Comment: @clemenskuehn - post now edited to provide some missing details, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are going down the wrong path guessing that data.table is based on UTC, I expect data.table, and `%inrange%` specifically, simply filter based on the data they are given.

I think there is some code missing from your example for how `df$TIMESTAMP` is converted from character data to a datetime type. Perhaps it is here that an implicit conversion to the local timezone is happening, or to a timezone that doesn't match the timezone of your start/end values.

Does the problem go away if you are explicit about timezone for both the `data.frame` values and the start/end values? For example:

```r
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

timezone <- "GMT"
df <- data.frame(TIMESTAMP = c("2021-06-18 11:36:00", "2021-06-18 11:38:00", "2021-06-18 11:40:00", "2021-06-18 11:42:00", "2021-06-18 11:44:00","2021-06-18 11:46:00", "2021-06-18 11:48:00"))
df$TIMESTAMP <- ymd_hms(df$TIMESTAMP, tz = timezone)

start <- ymd_hms("2021-06-18 11:36:00", tz = timezone)
end <- ymd_hms("2021-06-18 11:44:00", tz = timezone)
range <- data.table(start = start, end = end)

Event_1 <- setDT(df)[TIMESTAMP %inrange% range]
Event_1

TIMESTAMP
1: 2021-06-18 11:36:00
2: 2021-06-18 11:38:00
3: 2021-06-18 11:40:00
4: 2021-06-18 11:42:00
5: 2021-06-18 11:44:00
```

Comment: I guess you are right. I used Posixct date time format for the TIMESTAMP which may be the reason. Thanks!